# Getting camera frames from openCV output not the original frames of the cam

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, android

(In android), I want the applications that need to get camera frames, get from `openCV` output, not getting original frames of camera. for example, I have an application that opens camera and show cam frames like video, i want this application to get the camera frames from an interface output(some application that gets the original frames of cam and manipulate it).

The interface application acts/run like a background service and when the other applications use camera API, actually the android gives them the Interface App Output not the original frames 
 Is it possible?

Comment: You mean you want to read frames from the storage / other application?

Comment: not the storage, because the end applications use camera API for getting camera frames not storage

Comment: any idea, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your question looks a bit messy, but I`ll try to help.

You have to understand that OpenCV has **no** built in video encoder (or video interface, as you refer to it). The library relies upon third parties to get the job done. Your interface is already there (ta da!) just check to see which one have you compiled and keep in mind that you might have to code a C++ embedding for that.

Your Android environment should have one of these two:

- **GStreamer:** Is probably the best option, since it has an application sink, where you make it operate as a reasonable interface.

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/android/index.html

- **FFMpeg:** Does the job, most of the times quicker than GStreamer, but is a bit harder to code.

https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android

https://hackernoon.com/android-ndk-my-experience-with-ffmpeg-93dd7e4b9269

Comment: i think i should make an example: assume you want to make a LIVE in INSTAGRAM, and you want to make some changes on LIVE frames, i want to do something that when Instagram use cam API to get frames for LIVE, instead of getting the original frames(direct from cam), use the manipulated frames of my (INTERFACE) app, somehow the Instagram App doesn't know it uses an interface, as if it using pure(original) frames of camera. in other word, The interface app must tell the android that you must give my frames(the manipulated t frames of Interface) INSTEAD of real cam frames to any app that use camera

Comment: I think you should consider a few more things then. The Android platform architecture (https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/) won't let you do so. The Java API will request camera frames (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera#detect-camera) directly from the HAL layer therefore not allowing the _"app in the middle"_ thing.